# C++ Segmentation Fault - List of Structs with Sets

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, set

I have a struct defined as follows:

```
struct node {
int index;
std::set<StringRef> set1;
std::set<StringRef> set2;
std::set<StringRef> set3;
std::set<StringRef> set4;

};
```

I'm then looping through a `List` of `node` defined as follows:

```
 std::list<node> my_table;
```

I am now looping through this list and accessing `set1` and `set2`, but this leads to a segmentation fault.

```
for (std::list<liveness_node>::iterator it = liveness_table.end(); it != liveness_table.begin(); --it) {

            std::set<StringRef> in_temp = it->set1;
            std::set<StringRef> out_temp = it->set2;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dereferencing the `end` iterator.  You should use reverse iterators

```
for (auto it = liveness_table.rbegin(); it != liveness_table.rend(); ++it)
```

to traverse the list in reverse order.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (std::list<liveness_node>::iterator it = liveness_table.end(); it != liveness_table.begin(); --it)
```

You are trying to access `liveness_table.end()`, `end()` returns the last element + 1, you're not allowed to dereference and use `end()`. Instead, use a reverse iterator:

```
for (std::list<liveness_node>::reverse_iterator it = liveness_table.rbegin(); it != liveness_table.rend(); ++it)
```